# Can I use setCurrentItem in viewPager and use onPageSelected?

Tags: android, android-fragments

My problem is to initially load the fragment directly and also I want to call a method fragment is visible to the user.

For loading the correct fragment, I use `viewPager.setCurrentItem()` in `onCreate`. It works well.

**`FragmentActivity code`**:

```
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    mTabsAdapter = new TabsPlayerAdapter(this, mRadioList);
    mMainViewPager.setAdapter(mTabsAdapter);
    mMainViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    mMainViewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
}
```

To a method called fragment Current, I use the `onPageSelected viewPager`. It works well.

**`FragmentActivity code`**:

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onPageSelected - position: " + position);
    ((PlayerFragment) mTabsAdapter.mSparseFragment.get(position))
                                  .startAnnimation();
}
```

**`FragmentStatePagerAdapter code:`**

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(final int position) {
    Log.d(TAG, "getItem - position: " + position);
    Bundle args = new Bundle();  
        args.putString("num", mRadioModel.get(position).name);
        mSparseFragment.put(position, Fragment.instantiate  
                    (mContext,PlayerFragment.class.getName(), args));
        return mSparseFragment.get(position);
}
```

**`FragmentStatePagerAdapter code :`**

```
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    Log.d(TAG, "destroyItem - position: " + position);
    mSparseFragment.remove(position);
}
```

I can do these two things separately. But when I try to use the two together, I have a `"NullPointerException"` when I call my `fragment`.
I saw that `onPageSelected` is called before the `getItem` in my `Adapter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll know that items are available when onAttachedToWindow is called. At the moment you call setCurrentItem, the adapter has not been used to create views yet. (setAdapter is not sufficient to know that all have been inflated)

Else, you can consider setting your listener after setting the currentItem, therefore not having a animation when opening the fragment.

Comment: Thanks. The second propistion is perfect. The new problem is that they isn't annimation for the first fragment load, because `onPageSelected` is not triggered for page which is opened first...

Comment: It's a bug in ViewPager "on pageSelected" is not called for the first page. Follow this link for more description:                              http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27526

Comment: Thanks karn. But I think there is a solution for to solve the problem :(

Answer (score 2):

There is very easy work around:

In your adapter write:

```
public static interface FirstShot
{
    public void onFirstShot();
}


private FirstShot firstShot;
private boolean shot = false;

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0)
{
    if (!shot && firstShot != null)
    {
        shot = true;
        firstShot.onFirstShot();
    }

    // your code here
}
```

Now implement FirstShot in activity:

```
@Override
public void onFirstShot()
{
    viewPager.post(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            boolean needNotify = false;
            if (pager.getCurrentItem() == position) needNotify = true;
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, false);
            if (needNotify) onPageSelected(position);
        }
    });
}
```

onPageSelected() now calls!

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution didn't work for me, as I was still getting onPageSelected called before getItem created them.

I fixed it like so:

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    ...
    ...

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = createdFragments.get(position);
        if (fragment != null) {
            return fragment;
        }

        fragment = createNewFragment();
        createdFragments.put(position, fragment);

        return fragment;
    }

    public TabFragment getFragment(int position) {
        TabFragment fragment = createdFragments.get(position);
        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = (TabFragment) getItem(position);
        }
        return fragment;
    }
}
```

and then I use `adapter.getFragment()` to get a fragment by code and never get a null value.